# Trouble with matching variables to line in txt, and removing line

Tags: python

I am having trouble with matching variables to lines in txt, and removing the lines.

I am currently doing a hotel room booking program in which I am having trouble removing a booking from my text file.

This is how my lines in my text file are formatted:

first_name1, phonenumber1 and email 1 are linked to entry boxes

```
jeff;jeff@gmail.com;123123123;2019-06-09;2019-06-10;Single Room
 def edit_details(self,controller):

        f = open("Bookings.txt")
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        x = -1
        for i in lines:
            x += 1
            data = lines[x]
            first_name1 = str(controller.editName.get())
            phonenumber1 = str(controller.editPhone.get())
            email1 = str(controller.editEmail.get())

            checkfirst_name, checkemail, checkphone_num, checkclock_in_date, checkclock_out_date, checkroom = map(str, data.split(";"))

            if checkfirst_name.upper() == first_name1.upper() and checkemail.upper() == email1.upper() and checkphone_num == phonenumber1:
                controller.roomName.set(checkfirst_name)
                controller.roomEmail.set(checkemail)
                controller.roomPhone.set(checkphone_num)
                controller.roomCheckin.set(checkclock_in_date)
                controller.roomCheckout.set(checkclock_out_date)
                controller.roomSelect.set(checkroom)

                print(controller.roomName.get())
                print(controller.roomSelect.get())

                controller.show_frame("cancelBooking")
                break

            elif x > len(lines) - int(2):
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please Enter Valid Details")
                break
```

I have the user to enter their details to give me the variables but I don't know how to match these variables to the line in the text file to remove the booking.

Do I have to format these variables to match the line?
This is what i have tried but it deletes the last line in my file

```
line_to_match = ';'.join([controller.roomName.get(),controller.roomEmail.get(),controller.roomPhone.get()])
         print(line_to_match)

         with open("Bookings.txt", "r+") as f:
             line = f.readlines()
             f.seek(0)
             for i in line:
                 if i.startswith(line_to_match):
                    f.write(i)
             f.truncate()
```

Comment: Why are you storing in a file? How about a database? Atleast a file db?

Comment: this is for my school project, i already have the user to make the booking into this format and this is the last stage of my program

Comment: Can you also add the code about the variables that contains these details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kind of added a pseudocode here. You can join the variables using `;` and validate if the line startswith those details, like below.

```
first_name1, phonenumber1, email1 = 'jeff', 'jeff@gmail.com', '123123123'

line_to_match = ';'.join([first_name1, email1, phonenumber1])

for i in line:
    ...
    if i.startswith(line_to_match):
        # Add your removal code here
    ...
```

Comment: do i have to read the file to use line_to_match and then remove using write?

Comment: @Jefferyfromkmart Yes.

Comment: Dont use `readlines`. Iterate on the file object directly. `for line in open('file_name.txt'):`.